# How to make my file listing looks better with(out) using table?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using that kind of listing and editing description of my files: http://jsfiddle.net/GSC3x/5/ simply, when click on file name, it opens a jQuery form in the middle of the page, but let's say that I have a few files with different names, and then this thing looks ugly

(my case: http://derivativeofln.com/files.png ).

I want three columns of listing like this on single page, I was thinking about using tables, but when I'm trying to do it, my jQuery form doesn't open when I click on one of filenames.

What you suggest to use  here?

**@@UPDATE**

Here's (http://derivativeofln.com/fileslist.png) my list using

```
    li {float:left; width:200px;
```

But now I have only one column, how can I start the second column from the top of the page (as the first one started)?

Comment: [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/GSC3x/6/) is not an anwser to your question, it only should show how to reduce the html (avoid redundant code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use foating li's. Add this to your css:

```
li {float:left; width:200px;}
```

Adjust the width to the width of your page divided by 3

Comment: One of my problems solved, could you take a look on the update in my first post? Thanks!

Comment: Well, like I said: adjust the width. If the width of your page is 300px then you should set `li {float:left; width:150px;}` to get 2 columns.

Comment: @pawel Note that the list gets populated horizontally. You have to set the width of li to (width of container div/no of clumns)

Comment: For the difference in output of this code and mine: [This answer](http://jsfiddle.net/LXydK/) vs.  [my answer](http://jsfiddle.net/TcfJP/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
ul{
float: left;
width: 210px; /* The width of the column */
}

li{
width:200px;
}
```

Then end first ul and start a new ul whenever you want another column.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, unfortunately I can accept only one answer, but thanks!

Comment: No problem mate! Alwyays good to have alternatives right? Cheers!